# Spring Roo Multiple Vendor Databases

Tags: hibernate, jpa, web-applications, spring-roo

I have a Spring Roo application that I like that currently supports Oracle.  A customer likes the application, but only wants to use SQL Server.  I, of course, will port the application to SQL server to gain this customer.  The question is how.

Is it possible to have a single Spring Roo with JPA / Hibernate code base support two databases?  If so, what is a good way to approach it?

The alternative would be to have a code fork, which I would prefer to avoid, but will do if I have to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to port databases is to use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

To support two databases:

1. Add a new persistence unit to persistence.xml, for example named *persistenceUnit2*
2. In the applicationContext.xml setup a new DataSource, TransactionManager and EntityManagerFactory that uses the new persistence unit *persistenceUnit2*
3. Annotate the Entity to use the new persistence unit:

   > @RooJpaActiveRecord(persistenceUnit = "persistenceUnit2")
   >
   > class Entity